# In The Salesman (Asghar Farhadi), what did the intruder do?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, the-salesman

In the Asghar Farhadi film "The Salesman," the audience is kept in the dark most of the time about what actually happened in the apartment.

When Emad finds the perpetrator, at first he denies going into the bathroom, saying he only heard her screaming then fled.

But later, after Emad returns, he says "I behaved very badly... I was tempted." Is he admitting that he raped her,  or is he admitting that he just went into the bathroom and saw her naked? Or, is it intentionally ambiguous?

Comment: it could be either because culturally speaking the simple act of looking upon a naked woman that is not your spouse is considered a sinful act and something to be ashamed about; also given the subject and the cultural taboo around it, it might have been intentionally kept subtle rather than putting a too fine of a point on it, allowing the audience to measure their "feelings" about it up to the point "they" are willing to consider as to not distract from the larger plot, just my two cents